# The correct way to convert malloc to new

Tags: c++, c++11

I am changing c code to c++ code and this is how how i have converted malloc to new

```
frame.p_data = (uint8_t*)malloc(xres * yres * 4);
free(frame.p_data);


frame.p_data = (uint8_t*)operator new(xres * yres * 4);
delete(frame.p_data);
```

Is this the correct way to change from malloc to new and would the delete release all the data.

Comment: if you are using c++ you should probably also use c++ casts compared to c casts

Comment: Do you want to port the code to c++11 or just swap the ```malloc```s by ```new```s?  Smart pointers and RAII are a good way to write safe code

Comment: `malloc` is expecting sizes in bytes, not `new`. You should detail all the types in your example. Moreover, you wil need `delete[]`  and not `delete`.

Comment: `malloc` is perfectly good C++. There is no need to change anything. `new` is not inherently better or safer or anything.

Comment: What is the type of `frame.p_data`?

Comment: `new` - `delete`; `operator new` - `operator delete`. Do not use `delete` (and `delete[]`) for something returned by `operator new`. This is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should write

```
frame.pdata = new uint8_t[xres * yres * 4];
delete [] frame.pdata;
```

It is very rare to call the allocation function `operator new` explicitly, but if you do, you need to match it with the deallocation function, `operator delete`, otherwise the behaviour is undefined:

```
frame.p_data = (uint8_t*)operator new(xres * yres * 4);
operator delete(frame.p_data);
```

It's also not a problem to use `malloc` with primitive types, as long as you remember to deallocate with `free`, but it's easier to stick to `new`/`delete` and not have to remember.

Comment: Also with `new` you don't need a cast, and you don't need to remember to multiply by `sizeof(...)`.

Comment: I think it is wrong to newcomers to recommend using new/delete when they should use eg. a vector instead. see my answer as well for more details.

Comment: @darune What to use depends on the respective lifetimes of the vector and the data.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62301596/2261538) shows how to use new/delete, but this recommendation just does not seem right/complete.

*The correct* way (that will pass a mainstream code-review), is not replace it with `new`/`delete` in the first place, but go directly to containers/smart pointers. `std::vector` (or `std::array` if static size) has all the tools needed, since `std::vector` is the dynamic array in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). If the size tracking overhead is too much, then `std::unique_ptr` or `std::array`.

simplified example:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> data;

data.resize(xres * yres * 4);

uint8_t* pdata = data.data(); // <- access to raw buffer
```

A few guidelines regarding this:

https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete

https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-raw